# Specific elements from XML string to a datagridview or datatable (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview, datatable

I've only just recently begun working with XML strings. What I'm doing now is using a webservice to pull records from a database. It returns the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records count="2">
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
          <FieldDefinition id="13597" name="Statement" alias="Statement" />
          <FieldDefinition id="13598" name="Response" alias="Response" />
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <Record contentId="154321" moduleId="409">
        <Field id="13597" type="1">&lt;p&gt;This is a database record&lt;/p&gt;</Field>
        <Field id="13598" type="1">&lt;p&gt;This is a record&lt;/p&gt;</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="154755" moduleId="409">
        <Field id="13597" type="1">&lt;p&gt;This is another database record&lt;/p&gt;</Field>
        <Field id="13598" type="1">&lt;p&gt;And another corresponding record&lt;/p&gt;</Field>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a datatable/datagridview that will be displayed to the user. Which would be something like this:

```
|    Statement    |    Response    |
|This is a datab..| This is a corr.|
|This is another..| And another....|
```

I've tried the following code:

```
    private void WriteDataGrid(string xml)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xml, XmlNodeType.Document, null);
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Field";
    }
```

However it only managed to obtain this:

```
|    id | type  | Field_Text       |
|13597  | 1     | This is a...     |
|13598  | 1     | This is a corr...|
|13597  | 1     | This is anoth... |
|13598  | 1     | And anothe...    |
```

I plan to use the field id's from the xml to create unique columns, then set the values of the rows based on the enclosed values. But I'm unsure of how I should go about doing this. Could anyone help? Or is there a better way for me to achieve what I'm looking to do?

I'm aware it'd be much easier if the Elements were unique, but I'm unable to alter the webservices' output in any way.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I just realized I neglected to add that the XML string would contain HTML tags and markups 
(specifically *< p > < / p >*)
(*&lt &gt &amp* etc.) in the field texts. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could remove/escape/decode these before writing them to the datatable?

Comment: I'm surprised the "Field" is accepted as a DataMember name.

Comment: What is your `ds.Tables.Count` ? I think it is 2 and you need to select joins beginning from the MetaData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// XMLFile.xml file contains you xml response of service. and Final output is dt1 which contains data in format as you want.

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));
        dt = ds.Tables[5];

        var query = from s in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    group s by s.Field<string>("id") into g
                    select new { id = g.Key, field_text = g.ToList(),Count=g.ToList().Count };


        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        int maxRowid=0;
        foreach (var obj in query)
        {
            dt1.Columns.Add(obj.id);
            if(obj.Count>maxRowid)
            {
                maxRowid=obj.Count;
            }

        }

        // Add Rows to table         
        for (int count = 0; count < maxRowid; count++)
        {
            dt1.Rows.Add("", "");
        }

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var obj in query)
        {
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var dr in obj.field_text)
            {
                dt1.Rows[j][i] = ((DataRow)dr)["field_text"];
                j++;
            }
            i++;

        }
```

Comment: it works great! However, I've realized the field text gets enclosed in html tags (specifically <p></p>) and contains markups (e.g &amp, &lt etc.). Any suggestions on how I could remove this?

Comment: You can use Regular expression which will remove <>. 
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex.Replace("<p>This is a database record</p>", "<.*?>", string.Empty)